# How to re-use code between AngularJS client and Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, code-reuse

What are the best-practices in order to re-use/share code between an AngularJS client and a Node.js server?

I implemented an AngularJS application. Now I need to implement a RESTful-server providing the client with data. Some client-side angular services could be re-used on server, as for example third-party restful-clients to Facebook/Google/Twitter, which use intensively the angular dependency injection and which are dependent on `$http`, `$q` and many other services.

Ideally, as I really like the dependency injection framework included in AngularJS, I would find very nice to have a kind of server-framework based on AngularJS. A server-framework that includes the dependency injection framework and all angular-services that are not related to UI, and adding required server-side functionality like routing and authentication. But unfortunately, I didn't find any solution going that way. (Please tell me if such a framework exists!)

So, what would be an alternative, in order to at least enable code re-use between the client and the server? Particularly enabling code re-use for code depending on `$http`, `$q` and other AngularJS services included in the angular framework and angular-third-parties (like `angular-cache`).

Comment: Very interesting question. I think sharing models and some business logic is a very interesting idea. For example sharing schema, validation and services could turn into something awesome. Also you should look into node-di. It is a dependancy injection framework heavily inspired by AngularJS.

Answer (score 6):

#### Using angular in non-browser environment

Ben Clinkinbeard prepared angular distribution as a `commonJS` module ([HERE](https://github.com/bclinkinbeard/angular)), that can run in a non-browser environment:

> AngularJS compiled with jsdom and provided as a CommonJS module.
>   Intended for testing AngularJS code without depending on a browser.

---

If you want to be more cherry-picking you probably should wait for angular 2.0

#### Sharing code between client-side and server-side

And again... Ben Clinkinbeard. In **[THIS TALK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTPutZ99XWY)** he describes how to make use of browserify in an angular project. One cool feature of this approach is that you can declare your functions/objects as separate entities that are not coupled with angular anyhow; so they can be re-used in different contexts as well.

An example of it:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('someModule',[]);
...
app.factory('someService', require('./some/path.js'));
...
```

**`./some/path.js`**

```
module.exports = function(dep1, dep2){
  ...
  return {
     ...
  }
}
module.exports.$inject['dep1', 'dep2']; // for minification;
```

Comment: Hi, a little off topic but I'm doing something similar to what Ben mentioned in that talk. I really like the concept of separating the entity and making them modular. However, I don't know how much you've played with this concept but I'm having the hardest time trying to make my tests run. Everytime I run my mocha test I get `Argument 'SomeController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/ng/areq?p0=SomeController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined`. I've added the snippet if you want to look around [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rqwgpumy/).

Comment: It appears as though it's unaware of my controllers. Also, just a side note, `angular` which used to be Ben's package now has been official `angular`'s repo. So, if you do `npm i angular` it will instead give you the browser version of angular :(. But you can always put `"angular": "git://github.com/bclinkinbeard/angular"`in your `package.json` to grab from github.

Answer (score 1):

Using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for this make sense here.

Instead of defining your model/service inside of Angular like this:

```
(function (angular) {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('myModule').factory('MyModel', function (Deps) {
    var Model = function () {
      // do things here
    };
    return Model;
  });
}(window.angular));
```

You would do it this way splitting it in 2 files:

model.js:

```
(function (define) {
  "use strict";
  define([], function () {
    var factoryConstructor = function (deps) {
      var Model = function () {
        // do things here
      };
      return Model;
    };
    return factoryConstructor;
  });
}(window.define));
```

whatever.js

```
(function (define, angular) {
  "use strict";
  define(['Model'], function (Model) {
    angular.module("myModule").factory("myModel", Model);
  });
}(window.define, window.angular));
```

Check this [Videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yulGISBF8w) for a good example on how to implement this, there is also the [repository](https://github.com/ThomasBurleson/angularjs-Quizzler) from that video.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 1.x is pretty self contained framework. There is a plan to break functionalities apart,  but that will come in version 2. So this would be simple as just provide different implementation of $httpBackend for browser and node.js.

I have created a simple demo how to [share code between node.js and browser](https://github.com/matjaz/CommonJSClientServer) with CommonJS. This can be used for sharing validation, models etc.